# The freshclam can't update DB

Tags: linux, clamav

I am getting error **can't connect to port 80 of host db.vn.clamav.net (IP: 2606:4700::6810:da54)** when using freshclam.
I have pinged to domain db.vn.clamav.net it works fine, I think the reason lies in ipv6 but I don't know how to make freshclam use ipv4 instead of ipv6.
**this is what i get when i use freshclam on server**

```
ClamAV update process started at Tue Aug 31 19:03:14 2021
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.100.1 Recommended version: 0.103.3
DON'T PANIC! Read https://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading-clamav
main.cvd is up to date (version: 61, sigs: 6607162, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
connect_error: getsockopt(SO_ERROR): fd=4 error=101: Network is unreachable
Can't connect to port 80 of host db.vn.clamav.net (IP: 2606:4700::6810:da54)
Trying host db.vn.clamav.net (2606:4700::6810:db54)...
connect_error: getsockopt(SO_ERROR): fd=4 error=101: Network is unreachable
Can't connect to port 80 of host db.vn.clamav.net (IP: 2606:4700::6810:db54)
WARNING: getpatch: Can't download daily-24844.cdiff from db.vn.clamav.net
WARNING: getpatch: Can't download daily-24844.cdiff from db.vn.clamav.net
WARNING: getpatch: Can't download daily-24844.cdiff from db.vn.clamav.net
WARNING: Incremental update failed, trying to download daily.cvd
connect_error: getsockopt(SO_ERROR): fd=4 error=101: Network is unreachable
Can't connect to port 80 of host db.vn.clamav.net (IP: 2606:4700::6810:da54)
```

Comment: 'Network is unreachable' would indicate a lower-level connectivity issue. Are you able to connect to any internet service from this system?

Comment: I checked, Network works normally